# Serving CSS stylesheets that are linked to HTML files via the link tag in Node.js w/o a framework

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean

> I have been teaching myself Node.js by way of trial & error. I built a simple server using the Node.js HTTP class. I figured out that I can read a file asynchronously and serve the data using the asynchronous `fs.readFile(..., cbk)` callback method. What I don't understand at this point is how respond with all the other resources that the requests needs.

```
// "./index.js"

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res){
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

> For the sake of maintaining a single focus, I will use only **`Style-sheets`** as an example. Below is a super common link tag  that demonstrates how I typically tell the server that the pages needs a specific CSS file. It works fine on the front-end side of things. But, how to I handle a request from a link tag on the the server's side of things (or on the backend)?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/foo/bar/raboof.css">
```

###### Note: This is just a test project, but it doesn't use any frameworks, or even any modules (except for the dev-mod eslint). I would perfer to do this without 3rd party software/tools/frameworks etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your nodejs server is not programmed to send any style sheets when the browser requests them.

A nodejs server, like you've created, serves NO files by default.  It only serves files that you program it to serve.  So, your nodejs server is programmed to do one thing and one thing only and that's to deliver `index.html` no matter what URL is requested from it.

So, here's what happens:

1. User enters some URL for your site
2. Browser sends your server a request for that page
3. Your web server delivers `index.html`
4. Browser parses `index.html` and finds style sheet links
5. Browser sends your server a request for a style sheet link
6. Your server sends it `index.html`
7. Browser realizes "that's not a style sheet" and you get no styles

So, for your HTML server to work properly, you have to add code to look at the requested URL and, if it's a style sheet URL, it needs to send the proper file for that stylesheet, not just  blindly send `index.html` no matter what was requested.

Nobody says you need to use the Express library for this, but this is what it does.  It makes it very easy to configure what gets sent when different types of requests are made.  And, for requests of static resources like CSS files, it can even just be configured to automatically send them direct from the file system.

If you don't want to use Express for this, you don't have to, but then you will have to write your own code to serve the right data when different URLs are requested.

If you want to write your own code for this, you will have to create some sort of `if/else` or `switch` statement or table lookup that looks at `req.url` and then send the appropriate content that matches the requested URL.  Then, when the browser requests your style sheet, you can actually send it the appropriate style sheet, not `index.html`.  The same would be true for Javascript files, images, page icon, ajax requests or any resource on your server that your page references.

Comment: Holy cow! That answer was great. Thanks bud, that was more than I could have hoped for.

Answer (score 1):

Because your server-side code is written to handle all.http requests and deliver the same html content, regardless of the path.

try adding some if-else logic inside your handler, and deliver appropriate file based on the request path.

something like:

```
if(req.path === "" || req.path === "index.html")
     fs.read htnl file here
else if (req.path==="my.css")
     fs.read css file
```

learn to use browser dev tools (F12), which shows you exactly which requests the browser is making, what it sends, what it gets back - amongst many other things.

Comment: FYI, `req.path` isn't a valid property when using a plain HTTP server like the OP shows.  You would have to use `req.url` directly or parse it to remove things like the query string.

Comment: Thanks. I was typing from memory. I was trying to entice him to discover those things himself. He'll never learn if complete solutions are handed to him. It's evident that.he's a beginner.

Comment: But, obviously, your answer is more detailed. +1 from me.